# Manual pages for Linux kernel development?

Tags: linux, emacs, linux-kernel, manpage, linux-kernel-headers

I am taking an operating system course that requires making modifications to the Linux kernel. I would like to be able to view concise information on functions like `proc_create`*,* macros like `__init` ***,*** data types like `struct proc_dir_entry` and so on, as contained in headers like `linux/module.h`.

Is there a man page-like format that documents them as such? I am aware the source code is available [online](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source), but I'm hoping for a easy, readable way to gather information as I develop from the command line. I've been reading [LKMPG](https://sysprog21.github.io/lkmpg/), and while helpful, it is not concise. I use Emacs, so any suggestions from within Emacs will be well-taken.

I am running ArchLinux on a VM.

Comment: No, I don't think there is. There are textbooks with annotated Linux source code.

Comment: You can create it yourself by running `scripts/kernel-doc -man ...`.

Comment: Could you please specify more options @0andriy ?

Comment: `scripts/kernel-doc -man include/linux/module.h > module.h.man && man --local-file module.h.man` works for me. Result: `module_init(9)                                                                   Kernel Hacker's Manual                                                                   module_init(9)

NAME
       module_init - driver initialization entry point
` and so on...

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148433/105842.